# Updating python on redhat linux server

Tags: python, linux, redhat

I downloaded and installed python 2.7.6 manually on redhat linux server but I have trouble making it as a default python version, it still uses an old python 2.4.3 What should I do to make python 2.7.6 default.

Comment: art, why dont u search web. have u looked the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
export PATH=/path/to/2.7.6/bin:$PATH to your .bashrc file.
```